RESTEasy + Weld (CDI) in WAR file deployed to Jetty 11 doesnt seem to work
I'm trying to deploy a WAR file to Jetty 11 that includes REST service written using RESTEasy which uses CDI (Context & Dependency Injection) via Weld, but it doesn't seem to work.
The project is managed using Maven and I use jetty-maven-plugin to test it (with the command "mvn jetty:run").
Details:

RESTEasy 7.0.0.Alpha1 (I have to use 7.0.0.Alpha1, earlier versions use Jandex 2.X.X which conflicts with Weld)
Weld 5.1.2.Final
Jetty 11.0.19 (I'm using GWT 2.11.0 to implement client side and need to support JDK 11)
beans.xml is empty and lives in WEB-INF
Using Jakarta servlet 5.0, web.xml is minimal and only points to the class that extends RESTEasy Application.

Dependencies I use:
        <!-- RESTEasy -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0.Alpha1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0.Alpha1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-cdi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-cdi</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0.Alpha1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jakarta EE main APIs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Web Push -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nl.martijndwars</groupId>
            <artifactId>web-push</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.55</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SQL based db connection pooling -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-dbcp2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Weld CDI Support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

Maven jetty plugin:
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>11.0.19</version>
                </plugin>

The error that I get when I run "mvn jetty:run":
INFO: WELD-000900: 5.1.2 (Final)
May 08, 2024 7:08:55 PM org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.DiscoveryStrategyFactory create
INFO: WELD-ENV-000020: Using jandex for bean discovery
May 08, 2024 7:08:55 PM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup startContainer
INFO: WELD-000101: Transactional services not available. Injection of @Inject UserTransaction not available. Transactional observers will be invoked synchronously.
May 08, 2024 7:08:55 PM org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.WeldServletLifecycle initialize
INFO: WELD-ENV-001001: No supported servlet container detected, CDI injection will NOT be available in Servlets, Filters or Listeners

Naturally all my fields that are annotated with "@Inject" are null.
Why doesn't it detect a supported servlet container ?!
EDIT:
web.xml contents:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd"
         metadata-complete="false"
         version="5.0">

    <!-- Servlets -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>com.example.DemoApplication</servlet-name>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>com.example.DemoApplication</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Default page to serve -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.eclipse.jetty.cdi</param-name>
        <param-value>CdiDecoratingListener</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.EnhancedListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
     
</web-app>



What does your WEB-INF/web.xml look like?

Posted the web.xml contents

In your WEB-INF/web.xml you'll need a few things.
First one, set the CDI initialization mode.
<web-app ...>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.eclipse.jetty.cdi</param-name>
    <param-value>CdiDecoratingListener</param-value>
  </context-param>
</web-app>

Then enable the cdi module in your ${jetty.base}
$ cd /path/to/myjettybase
$ java -jar /path/to/jetty-home/start.jar --add-module=cdi

If this doesn't work, you might need to enable the enhanced initialization of the weld codebase.
<web-app ...>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.EnhancedListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>


I run jetty using "mvn jetty:run". What is the equivalent to "--add-module=cdi" in the jetty-maven-plugin" ?

I updated the web.xml that I use (following your suggestions, as seen in the post) - didnt change the outcome.
